What does "vultures on someone's shoulder" mean?
https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/4745539-fetterman-defends-biden-debate-performance/
says

“I refuse to join the Democratic vultures on Biden’s shoulder after
the debate. No one knows more than me that a rough debate is not the
sum total of the person and their record,” Fetterman posted on the
social platform X.

What does "vultures on someone's shoulder" mean?
Is a vulture on a hunter's shoulder an aid to the hunter?

Vultures are birds that feast on dead animals and people, and in old Western movies they used to circle in the air above people lost in the desert, waiting for them to die. If a person was very close to death perhaps the vultures would be bold enough to perch on that person's shoulder. The death in the figure of speech is political death, not literal death, and the figurative vultures are Democrats ready to predict Biden's electoral doom.

This is a bit of a mixed metaphor. The usual metaphor is "vultures circling," and comes from vultures flying overhead, waiting to eat a creature that they believe will be soon dead. It means that people are waiting to take advantage of somebody else failing.
It seems clear to me that Fetterman intended the same broad meaning as "vultures circling." He may have intended to convey as well that the vultures are acting friendly (and thus convey that Biden's critics are fair weather allies), or that the vultures are even closer than overhead. Alternately, he may just have slightly mangled the phrase because he was speaking without preparation. It's difficult to say which is true, but I would take it identically to "vultures circling above Biden."

It's not even clear what the other part of the mixed metaphor was. It makes me think of a parrot on one's shoulder, but maybe closer is the "angel and demon on your shoulder" trope. Or more likely was the notion of someone looking/looming over your shoulder, i.e. uncomfortably close.

Is the other metaphor "hawk or falcon on a hunter's shoulder"?

@AndyBonner - birds often feature in the figurative imagination. I once read an interview with a young man who was an ordained monk living in the community, and not wearing a habit. He was asked how he coped with carnal temptation, and he said 'I can't stop the birds from flying over my head, but I don't have to let them nest in my hair'.

@Tim No, definitely not. A hawk or falcon on ones shoulder is something useful that you can send out at will to do your bidding. Fetterman's comment was entirely negative, so that's clearly not a meaning he's intending to convey (though he may have gotten the imagery confused without intending the meaning). As Andy said, it's unclear what else he was trying to pull into the metaphor; it's not any usual set phrase.
